# ElasticSearch - Get key of searched value

Tags: elasticsearch

I search for key word **machine4** in my ES . My python client is simply:

```
result = es.search('machine4', index='machines')
```

Result look like this

```
[
    {
        "_score": 0.13424811,
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "2",
        "_source": {
            "date": "**20180601**",
            "deleted": [],
            "changed": [
                "machine1",
                "machine2",
                "machine3"
            ],
            "**added**": [
                "**machine4**",
                "machine5"
            ]
        },
        "_index": "contacts"
    },
    {
        "_score": 0.13424811,
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "3",
        "_source": {
            "date": "**20180701**",
            "deleted": [
                "machine2"
            ],
            "**changed**": [
                "machine1",
                "**machine4**",
                "machine3"
            ],
            "added": [
                "machine7"
            ]
        },
        "_index": "contacts"
    }
]
```

So we can easily see:
In date 20180601 , machine4 belonged to added.
In date 20180701 , machine4 belonged to changed.

I can write another function to analyze the result. Basically loop through every key,value of each items and check if the searched keyword belong, like this:

```
for result in search_results['hits']['hits']:
    source_result = result['_source']
    for key,value in source_result.items():
        if 'machine4' in value:
            print key
```

However, I wonder if ES having API to detect which key/mapping/field that the searched keywords belonged to ? In this case is **added** of the 1st result, and **changed** in 2nd result

Thank you so much
Alex

Comment: Alex would it be possible for you to perform a change in the data model? So you can ingest flatten object per `machine` where the `action_tags` are "deleted,changed,added" and also it contains the `date`, one record per machine-action, so you can perform proper and faster queries and aggregations on a timeseries manner? you could also have the benefit to use Kibana for quick plotting it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer seems to be that no, Elasticsearch doesn't have a way to do this out of the box, because Lucene doesn't have it, as per [this thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/best-way-to-return-which-field-matched/4140)

Elasticsearch has the concept of [highlights](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#field-match), however. These could be useful, but they do require you to have some idea about which fields the match may be in.

[The ES Python search documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search) suggests there's no way to do that as a parameter to search, but you could create a custom query and pass it on as the `q` argument. It would look something like:

```
q = {"query" : {"match": { "content": "'machine4'" }}, "highlight" : {"fields" : {"added" : {}, "updated": {}}}}
result = es.search(index='machines', q=q)
```

Hope this is helpful!